# How do I tell WebSphere to ignore JAX-RS annotations?

Tags: websphere, jax-rs, war, websphere-8

I am trying to deploy my WAR file to WebSphere 8.5.5. It works in Tomcat, WebLogic, Jetty, JBoss, but fails in WebSphere.
The stack trace starts in `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.scanForHandlesTypesClasses()` method, which tries to create instance of `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AtomPojoProvider` class. Other application servers don't create `AtomPojoProvider` instance on start-up.
`AtomPojoProvider` has annotation `javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider`. How do I tell WebSphere to ignore this JAX-RS annotation?

UPDATE: Tried the following:

- com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.DisableIBMJAXRSEngine=true;

- metadata-complete=true in web.xml;

- Check metadata-complete in Admin console.

It looks like WebSphere 8.5.5 ignores those settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed web-app version to 2.4 in web.xml:

```
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the following JVM property:

```
com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.DisableIBMJAXRSEngine=true
```

However after disabling the JAX-RS runtime environment, JAX-RS features are not available, including base JAX-RS runtime capabilities, Enterprise JavaBeans (EJB) runtime integration, Java Contexts and Dependency Injection (JCDI) runtime integration, and Servlet 3.0 web container integration.

For more details check [Disabling the JAX-RS runtime environment](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_jaxrs_disable_runtime.html?lang=en).

So you may also consider removing your third party engine from application and try to use one provided with WebSphere.

Comment: >>com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.DisableIBMJAXRSEngine=true<< Tried, does not work.